# Why does C# "var" keyword not work when looping through a Visio Masters collection?

Tags: c#, type-inference

I am using the Visio API to loop through each `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Master` object in a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Document`'s `Masters` collection.

When I use `var` as follows, the compiler only recognizes `master` as type `object` and throws an error:

```
foreach (var master in doc.Masters)
```

Instead, I have to do this for it to work:

```
foreach (Visio.Master master in doc.Masters)
```

Why is this happening? Usually I have no problems using `var` in a foreach loop.

**Edit**: the error I get when I use the `Open` method on `master` is:

> 'object' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Open' and no extension method
>   'Open' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'object' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My guess is that `doc.Masters` is returning `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<object>` - i.e. it's weakly typed.

Basically there's an implicit cast in the second version - it's doing (assuming the non-generic form):

```
using (IEnumerator enumerator = doc.Masters.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Visio.Master master = (Visio.Master) enumerator.Current;
        // Loop body
    }
}
```

It only knows what type you're interested in because you've specified that as the type for the variable. (This is a *bit* like specifying the type of a range variable, which makes the compiler call `Cast<T>()` in the expansion of a LINQ query expression.)

Comment: It is definitely weakly typed, because it comes from COM - and all COM-originated sequences are plain `IEnumerable`s (because there's nowhere to get type annotations for elements from).

Comment: @Pavel: That's what I was guessing, but my COM knowledge is as weak as the collections it exposes ;)

Answer (score 2):

The var keyword doesn't work whenever the collection (or whatever you use it for) is not strongly typed. In other words: When it is clear that the right side of the expression returns a certain type, the var works.

Example:

```
var name = "Markus";   // Must be string
var form = new Form(); // Must be form
```

However, when the type is 'object', then var will also represent an object.

Example:

```
var myList = new ArrayList(); // var = ArrayList
foreach (var item in myList) // item = object
{ }
```

However, if the list is strongly typed, var will work as expected:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in myList)  // item = string
{ }
```

I do not know the Visio API, but my assumption would be that var turns into an object and thus is not very useful to you.